# C6385 warning in VS (in regard to dynamic arrays)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, warnings

My code is supposed to print the Union and Intersection of two sets of integers.
Why do I get this warning?

[image: screenshot]

Is it because I use dynamic arrays and it's size could be anything in runtime?

How can I fix it? My code works fine but this warning really bugs me.

P.S: I know it would be a lot easier to use `std::vector` but my teacher required to use arrays.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void UnionFunc(int[],int,int[],int,int[],int&);
void IntersectionFunc(int[], int, int[], int, int[], int&);

int main() {
    int* A;
    int SizeA;
    int* B;
    int SizeB;
    int* Union;
    int UnionSize=0;
    int* Intersection;
    int IntersectionSize=0;

    cout << "Enter the Size of First Set : "; cin >> SizeA;
    A = new int[SizeA];
    cout << "Enter the Size of Second Set : "; cin >> SizeB;
    B = new int[SizeB];
    Intersection = new int[SizeA >= SizeB ? SizeB : SizeA];
    Union = new int[SizeA + SizeB];

    for (int i = 0; i < SizeA; i++) {
        cout << "Set A[" << i + 1 << "] = ";
        cin >> A[i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < SizeB; i++) {
        cout << "Set B[" << i + 1 << "] = ";
        cin >> B[i];
    }
    
    UnionFunc(A,SizeA,B,SizeB,Union,UnionSize);
    IntersectionFunc(A, SizeA, B, SizeB, Intersection, IntersectionSize);

    cout <<endl<< "Union Set : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < UnionSize; i++) {
        cout << Union[i] << ",";
    }

    cout <<endl <<"Intersection Set : ";
    for (int i = 0; i < IntersectionSize; i++) {
        cout << Intersection[i] << ",";
    }


    system("pause>n");
    return 0;
}

void UnionFunc(int A[],int SizeA, int B[],int SizeB, int Union[],int &UnionSize) {
    
    //Adding First Array to Union Array
    for (int i = 0; i < SizeA;i++) {
        Union[i] = A[i];
        UnionSize++;
    }

    //Checking if second array's elemnts already exist in union arry, if not adding them
    bool exist;

    for (int i = 0; i < SizeB; i++) {
        exist = false;
        for (int j = 0; j < UnionSize; j++) {
            if (B[i] == Union[j] ) {
                exist = true;
            }
        }
        if (exist == false) {
            Union[UnionSize] = B[i];
            UnionSize++;
        }
    }

}

void IntersectionFunc(int A[], int SizeA, int B[], int SizeB, int Intersection[], int& IntersectionSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < SizeA; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < SizeB; j++) {
            if (A[i] == B[j]) {
                Intersection[IntersectionSize] = A[i];
                IntersectionSize++;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning C6385 in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649678/warning-c6385-in-visual-studio)

Comment: @sebastian I agree that the linked question is very similar (even a duplicate, maybe), but the answer given there is simply to "turn off" the warning. In this case, there is a better way, which is not really possible/appropriate in the case of the 'dupe'.

Comment: @AdrianMole, MS acknowledged it's a bug, and said they'd fix it. Granted, that was 8 months ago :P

Comment: @ChrisMM But in this case, it may not *always* be a false positive.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is it because I use dynamic arrays and it's size could be anything in
> runtime?*

Yes! The compiler doesn't know (and, as your code is written, *can't* know) that both `SizeA` and `SizeB` will be 'valid' numbers - so the size of the three `int` arrays you create could be less than is required for the `Intersection[i]` 'read' to be valid.

A 'quick and dirty' fix for this is to provide a *visible* guarantee to the compiler that the arrays you create will be at least a certain size, like this:

```cpp
A = new int[max(1,SizeA)]; // Compiler can now 'see' a minimum size
```

And similarly for the other allocations you make with the `new[]` operator.

*(I have tested this with VS2019, adding the `max(1,SizeA)` and `max(1,SizeB)` 'fixes' to **just** the allocations of `A` and `B` and the warning is removed.)*